# For an app is using Room Database, concept is database interactions run in background, how do I ensure a query completes before continuing

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have implemented an Android Room Database in my application. My understanding is that the Room Database interactions are to be run in the background independent of the the UI thread.  If my application takes actions based on the results of a query to the database, what is the best design technique to ensure that the results of the query have completed before the executing additional code.

What I am experiencing in testing is that the query is completing well after my code continues after the submission of the query (duh!!).  If a query result is depended upon for continuing execution of the program, can I tell Room to not run the query in the background and suspend running a next line of code until results have been returned.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the best design technique to ensure that the results of the query have completed before the executing additional code

Step #1: Have your Room DAO expose a reactive API (e.g., `LiveData`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines)

Step #2: React to the results of those API calls and advance in your app at that point (e.g., from an `Observer` of the `LiveData`)